# For loop inside List<Object>{ };

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `DropDownList` for `year` selection and I filled it with following default values.

Instead of which, is there any option to fill it using for-loop like I have given in below code as comment.

```
var yr = new List<Object>
{ 
    new { value=0 ,text="--Select--"},
    new { value = 2015 , text = "2015" },
    new { value = 2016 , text = "2016" },
    new { value = 2017 , text = "2017" },
    new { value = 2018 , text = "2018" },
    new { value = 2019 , text = "2019" },
    new { value = 2020 , text = "2020" },
    //new { for(int i = 2010;i <= DateTime.Now.Year+5; i++) value = i , text = i },
};
ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(yr, "value", "text");
```

Comment: `List<T>` has an "Add" method...

Comment: Yes - that has an Add method as well. (List<Object> is a List<T>...)

Comment: You can use the loop, but create a `SelectListItem` not `object` and just assign that to `ViewBag.Year` - there is no need to the `SelectList` constructor. And add the `labelOption` in the `DropDownListFor()` method, not in the controller.

Comment: And you can simplify it even further using the `Enumerable.Range()` method

Comment: `ViewBag.Year = Enumerable.Range(2010, DateTime.Now.Year + 5 - 2010).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize your `List` with value `0` by using collection initializer and then use `for` loop like this:

```
var yr = new List<Object> {new {value = 0, text = "--Select--"}};
for (var i = 2015; i <= 2020; i++)
{
    yr.Add(new { value = i, text = i.ToString() });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you ?

```
List<object> l = new List<object>();
for (int i = 2015; i < 2020; i++ )
    l.Add(new { value = i, text = i });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use method [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) of List.

i.e.

```
for (int i = 2015; i < DateTime.Now.Year+5; i++ )
{
    yr.Add(new { value = i, text = i });
}
```